# Rollup'd react component css styles aren't being added to SSR document in NextJS

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, rollup

I've made a small npm package that exports a single component. The component is styled using SCSS modules, and bundled together using Rollup. It all seemed to work fine, but once I imported it into a NextJS project I noticed that the styles aren't being applied to the SSR'd document sent down from NextJS (they do eventually get applied, but there is a blip where the component is un-styled).

This is my first time creating an npm package and my first time using Rollup, and I'm having a tough time figuring out how to fix this issue. Maybe I need to not bundle the CSS into the .js files and instruct users to import the css files themselves? I was trying to avoid having that extra step, though. Perhaps using CSS-in-JS could solve the issue, but I'd rather not add a dependency for that if I can avoid it.

Any pointers would be much appreciated!

My Rollup config looks like this:

```
const config = [
  {
    input: "src/lib/index.ts",
    output: [
      {
        file: pkg.main,
        format: "cjs",
        sourcemap: true,
      },
      {
        file: pkg.module,
        format: "esm",
        sourcemap: true,
      },
    ],
    plugins: [
      peerDepsExternal(),
      resolve(),
      commonjs(),
      url(),
      svgr(),
      typescript({ tsconfig: "./tsconfig.json", rootDir: "src/lib" }),
      postcss({
        modules: true,
      }),
      terser(),
      bundleSize(),
      visualizer(),
    ],
  },
  {
    input: "dist/esm/types/index.d.ts",
    output: [{ file: "dist/index.d.ts", format: "esm" }],
    plugins: [
      dts(),
      del({ hook: "buildEnd", targets: ["dist/cjs/types", "dist/esm/types"] }),
    ],
  },
];
```

And I'm not sure if it's relevant, but my tsconfig looks like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationDir": "types",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "plugins": [{ "name": "typescript-plugin-css-modules" }]
  },
  "include": ["src/lib/customModules.d.ts", "src/**/*"]
}
```

Comment: Hello, are you get any Solutions. I am facing same problem.

Comment: same issue mate, the style added to the rollup component but is not reflecting in nextjs project

Answer (score 1):

Next.js, due to its dual compilation process for both server and client-side code, does not support the approach of injecting CSS.

Consequently, the solution is to generate or emit a standalone CSS file for your library and subsequently incorporate it into your Next.js application.

You should import your built css file inside the Next.js application layout file src/app/layout.jsx or tsx file.

```
import 'my-component/index.css';

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>{children}</body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

Please check this ref: [How to use styled-components with rollup and next.js - css not imported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77251063/how-to-use-styled-components-with-rollup-and-next-js-css-not-imported)

Answer (score -1):

In Next.js, when using CSS-in-JS libraries or certain styling methods for React components, you might encounter issues with Server-Side Rendering (SSR) where styles applied by components are not included in the initial HTML document. Here are a few potential reasons and solutions:

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).