# How to use styled-components with rollup and next.js - css not imported

Tags: reactjs, next.js, styled-components, rollupjs

I have the components getting imported from my component library internal to my company.

The component library uses rollup:

`rollup.config.mjs`

```
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import json from '@rollup/plugin-json';
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import typescript from '@rollup/plugin-typescript';
import dts from 'rollup-plugin-dts';
import peerDepsExternalPlugin from 'rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external';
import postcss from 'rollup-plugin-postcss';
import { babel } from '@rollup/plugin-babel';
import { createRequire } from 'node:module';
const requireFile = createRequire(import.meta.url);
const packageJson = requireFile('./package.json');

export default [
  {
    input: 'src/index.ts',
    output: [
      {
        file: packageJson.main,
        format: 'cjs',
        sourcemap: true,
      },
      {
        file: packageJson.module,
        format: 'esm',
        sourcemap: true,
      },
    ],

    plugins: [
      babel({ babelHelpers: 'bundled' }),
      resolve(),
      commonjs(),
      typescript({
        exclude: ['**/tests/', '**/stories/'],
      }),
      json(),
      postcss({
        extensions: ['.css'],
      }),
      peerDepsExternalPlugin(),
    ],
  },
  {
    input: 'dist/index.d.ts',
    output: [{ file: 'dist/index.d.ts', format: 'es' }],
    plugins: [dts()],
    // not sure we want this (external) option here
    external: [/\.css$/]
  },
];
```

Then I build it.

And from the nextjs application I have it in the package json. use `yarn link` to link the two repos (and I know yarn link is working).

But none of the styles get passed through to my next js application using my component library.

I've tried changing my `next.config.js` to this and it did nothing.

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
module.exports = {
  reactStrictMode: false,
  compiler: {
    styledComponents: {
      // Enabled by default.
      cssProp: true,
    },
  },
};
```

This is my `.babelrc`

```
{
  "plugins": ["babel-plugin-styled-components"]
}
```

Any help here would be incredible.

Answer (score 3):

This approach of **keeping the CSS injection via style tags inline to the generated JavaScript does not work** with Next.js since it generates has two compilations i.e. one for server and another for client-side code. Imagine you have a simple component in your library:

```
import React from 'react';

import style from './style.css';

export function MyComponent() {
  return (
    <div className={style.root}>
      <p>Hello world</p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

And, your CSS file is like this:

```css
/* style.css */
.root {
  display: flex;
  font-size: 48px;
}
```

Then the bundle file generated by Rollup will be:

```js
import React from 'react';

// Very simplified version.
function styleInject(css) {

  var head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
  var style = document.createElement('style');
  
  style.styleSheet.cssText = css;

  head.appendChild(style);
}

// Side effects (These won't be included in the client-side bundle)
var css_248z = ".root {\n  display: flex;\n  font-size: 48px;\n}\n";
styleInject(css_248z);

function MyComponent() {
  return React.createElement(
    "div",
    { className: css_248z.root },
    React.createElement("p", null, "Hello world")
  );
}

export { MyComponent };
```

The problem here is that Next.js won't include the `styleInject` function in the client-side bundle and running this code on server-side is meaningless.

Thus **the only way is to actually generate/emit a standalone CSS file for your library and then include that in your Next.js app.** Change the `rollup-plugin-postcss` configuration like this:

```js
postcss({
  // Extract the CSS into a standalone file.
  extract: true,
  // You will have to use CSS Modules.
  modules: true,
  extensions: ['.css'],
}),
```

This will generated `index.css` file:

```css
/* Name mangled */
.style_root__WnIqm {
  display: flex;
  font-size: 48px;
}
```

And, the bundled JS code will simply refer to this CSS class leaving the application developer to ensure that the CSS in properly injected:

```
// Bundled JS File by the Rollup after extraction
import React from 'react';

var style = { "root": "style_root__WnIqm" };

function MyComponent() {
  return React.createElement(
    "div",
    { className: style.root },
    React.createElement("p", null, "Hello world")
  );
}

export { MyComponent };
```

Finally, in your Next.js application layout file `src/app/layout.jsx` or `tsx` file, you can import this CSS:

```
import './globals.css';

// IMPORTANT: Library import CSS
import 'my-awesome-library/index.css';

export const metadata = {
  title: 'Create Next App',
  description: 'Generated by create next app',
}

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>{children}</body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

Comment: Could you share a repository with this working build?

Comment: @Mathiasfc, I can take some time. I will see if I can do that over the weekend!

Comment: I would also be interested in a working repository